# Ransack Search Results - to_xls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a ransack search form which is working wonderfully, I would like to add an export for the user to send the contents of the result set to an XLS file.

I have implemented the to_xls sucessfully as well, however it is giving me back the fullest possible scope of the object I am searching, and not the filtered results that are shown in the view.

```
def index

  @search = Expense.search(params[:q])
  @expense_list = @search.result.sort_by(&:expense_date) 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml { render :xml => @expense_list }
      format.xls { send_data @expense_list.to_xls, :filename => '123.xls'}
    end

end
```

Does it have something to do with how ransack uses the GET method?  Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you sent the `q` filter parameters when asking for the xls file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is such a hack, after spending many hours of not getting it, I used it anyway.

```
<a href="/expenses.xls?<%= request.fullpath.split("?")[1]  %>">make xls</a>
```

so basically it takes the searchpath after the ?, then adds it to your model.xls output path and then it works.  I hate it myself, there must be a better way, but deadlines.

There was a good [link](http://www.savagevines.com/post/2011/9/15/export_data_as_csv_with_rails_3_and_ruby_192/) here.

Answer (score 1):

[Ronin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729622/ronin) gave a simple solution to [this related question, but with CSV instead of XLS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17113976/1877184) . In my case, using Ronin's answer, I just rewrote the link to work with XLS as shown below

```
<%= link_to "Download Excel", reports_path(params.merge(format: "xls")) %>
```

Comment: Note that since the implemantation of Strong Params in Rails 5 (2016), this needs to be written as:
```link_to 'Download Excel', objects_path( {q: params.require(:q).permit(:attribute_one_eq, :attribute_two_cont)}.merge({format: :xls}))```

Answer (score 0):

```
%= link_to "Download Excel", yours_controller_path(params.merge(format: "xls")) %>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.