# Rails Unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, parameters, search-form

I am trying to implement a simple search and sort for my webapp. I am following the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax) and this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form).

My application helper for sortable function which I am using as link is:

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
      title ||= column.titleize
      css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
      direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
      link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
    end
```

I am using these in the view. In the controller I am using white listing as:

```
 @listingssearch.where(:vehicletype => 'Car').order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

Private Methods for sanitization:

```
 private
     def sort_column
          Listing.column_names.include?(params) ? params[:sort] : "rateperhour"
        end

        def sort_direction
          %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
        end
```

I tried using merge in the private method:

```
(Listing.column_names + params) but its not working
```

For the helper methods **I am getting an error when I am trying to provide search params** to the sorting link: unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash

It shows the error is for merge

```
link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
```

The otherway around works fine:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for listings_path, :method => 'get' do %>

        <%= hidden_field_tag :direction, :value => params[:direction] %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :sort,:value => params[:sort] %>



        <div class= "col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12" style = "margin: auto;">
            <h6 style = "color:#7C064D;"><strong> PICK A DATE  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></strong>
            <%= date_field_tag :startdate, params[:startdate], placeholder: 'DATE' %>           
            </h6>
        </div>  

        <div class= "col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12" style = "margin: auto;">    
        <p>     
            <%= text_field_tag :near, params[:near], placeholder: ' Destination' %>
            <%= text_field_tag :radius, params[:radius], placeholder: ' Search Radius' %>
        </p>
        </div>      
        <div class= "col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12" style = "margin: auto;">    
        <p>     
            <%= text_field_tag :min, params[:min], placeholder: ' Minimum Rate Per Hour' %>
            <%= text_field_tag :max, params[:max], placeholder: ' Maximum Rate Per Hour' %>
        </p>
        </div>

        <div class= "col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12" style = "margin-top: 10px;">        
            <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-info", style: "width: 40%; background-color: #E20049; border: #e20049;" %>
            <%= link_to 'View All', root_path, class: "btn btn-info", style: "width: 40%; background-color: #E20049; border: #e20049;" %>
        </div>

        <!-- <div class= "col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6" style = "margin-top: 10px;">      

        </div> -->


    <% end %>
```

**My question is How to persist search params in sort helper methods in rails 5? What I am doing wrong?**

Answer (score 109, accepted):

In Rails 5, `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from `Hash`, in an attempt to discourage people from using `Hash`-related methods on the request parameters without explicitly filtering them.

As part of [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/28734), which was backported into Rails 5.1 and partially into Rails 5.0, an exception is raised if you try to call `to_h` on the parameters object without calling `permit`.

Calling `merge` on the original `params` object (`params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil)`) returns a new `ActionController::Parameters` object with the same `permitted` status (that is, `permit` has not been called on it). The `link_to` method then ends up calling `to_h` on that object, which raises the exception.

If you know which parameters should be allowed in the link, you can call `permit` with those listed.

```
params.permit(:param_1, :param_2).merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil)
# OR
params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil).permit(:param_1, :param_2, :sort, :direction, :page)
```

If you don't know which parameters could be included in the link, then it's possible to call `request.parameters.merge(...)` (as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46029217/7151673)) or `params.to_unsafe_h.merge(...)`. However, as pointed out in comments, this is a security risk when the result is passed to `link_to`, as a parameter like `host` would be interpreted as the actual host for the link instead of a query parameter. There are several other keys that also have special meaning in `link_to` (everything accepted by `url_for`, plus `:method`), so it's generally a risky approach.

Comment: Do you mean passing search and sort params in the resource permit method itself?

Comment: @SauravPrakash I expanded the answer a bit to include some examples and also to make a slight correction to what's causing the exception. Does that address your question?

Comment: Thanks! Passing params explicitly will help protect against sql injections. This would be the right way to proceed instead of request.params. Although both works.

Comment: This actually is risky, because someone can include say `host` in the query params of the URL they ask your app for, and your app will generate a url to some other host.

Comment: @jrochkind Good point for the options that circumvent strong parameters; I'll edit to note that. I don't believe the options that explicitly name the allowed parameters would be vulnerable to that.

Comment: Note that this can get tricky when you're trying to pass parameters as well as ```.merge({format: :csv})``` - e.g. if you're trying to export a ransack search.  The correct format for your link_to needs to be: ```impairments_path({q: params.require(:q).permit(:location_id_eq, :system_name_cont, :classification_eq, :ended_eq)}.merge({format: :csv}))```.   
  
I posted a more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76734567/16952511)

Answer (score 50):

You can use this hack:

```
params.to_enum.to_h
```

I think rails developers will restrict it when they know it's the way to use unpermitted parameters. :)

Comment: Useful for troubleshooting routing issues for the time being.

Answer (score 12):

you can try to use request.parameters.merge, below is sample for your code above

```
<%= link_to title, listings_path(request.parameters.merge({:sort => "column", :direction => "direction", :page => nil})), :class => "form-control css_class" %>
```

Comment: Thank You! I used your suggestion and found out one needs to add request.params.merge instead of params.merge

So the final return will be: link_to title, request.params.merge({:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil}), {:class => "css_class" }  which worked in rails 5

Comment: Wouldn't this open you up to xss attacks?

Answer (score 8):

You can also overwrite by doing `params.permit!` This may have security risks though, so be careful using this.

Answer (score 6):

Since no one suggested this. So here is one way that we can use `params.to_unsafe_hash` which will convert the strong parameters to a hash.

For example:

```
(byebug) values
<ActionController::Parameters {"country"=>"RU", "city"=>"Moscow", "street"=>"1 First Street", "zip"=>"123456"} permitted: false>
(byebug) values.to_unsafe_hash
{"country"=>"RU", "city"=>"Moscow", "street"=>"1 First Street", "zip"=>"123456"}
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe if you pass column to permit it should get you working again!

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, params.permit(column).merge(sort: column, direction: direction, page: nil), { class: css_class }
end
```

Comment: Perfect response and context.
as you always know with this function which is the allowed field (column)