# ActionController::UnfilteredParameters - unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash - Rails 5.1.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-5.1.6

I am getting this error in following code

```
link_to params.to_h.merge(query_hash), options do
  raw("#{title} " + fa_icon(icon))
end
```

To fix it i tried following things which didn't work mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46029524/297087)

```
 request.parameters.merge(query_hash)
```

also

```
safe_params = params.permit(params.keys.flatten)
link_to safe_params.to_h.merge(query_hash), options do
  raw("#{title} " + fa_icon(icon))
end
```

But nothing works for me, has anybody gone through such error.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Salil. What is output `params.to_h.merge(query_hash)` when the link works? is it url?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a late response but I had a similar problem and found a solution so it may be helpful to others.

I had a similar issue with a link where I was passing the ransack parameters in Active Admin.  My link to looked similar to yours:

```
link_to('PRIMARY EMAILS ONLY', export_primary_emails_admin_admin_areas_path(format: "csv", params: params[:q]))
```

Even though I had set the strong parameters, as per the documentation, I kept getting the same error.  The only way I could get this to work was to force the parameter to be permitted using this directly before the link_to.

```
params[:q].permit!
```

It is effectively doing the same thing as strong params would in allowing anything in the "q" parameter(s).

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminArea do
  permit_params q: []
end
```