# How to fix ActionView parameters hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Running Locally
Rails 5.2.6
Ruby 2.5.1p57
upgraded from Rails 5.1.7 (everything worked fine before upgrading)

```
ActionView::Template::Error (unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash):
     6:   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     7:     <% choices.each do |c| %>

     8:       <li class="<%= "active" if params[:sort] == "#{c[0]}-#{c[1]}" %>">
     9:       <%= link_to url_for(params.merge(sort: "#{c[0]}-#{c[1]}")) do %>
    10:         <%= c[0].humanize %> <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-<%= c[1] == 'asc' ? 'up' : 'down' %>"></i>
    11:       <% end %>
    12:       </li>

app/views/shared/_sort_dropdown.html.erb:9:in `block in _app_views_shared__sort_dropdown_html_erb___1598759478239571724_70137340818660'
app/views/shared/_sort_dropdown.html.erb:7:in `each'
app/views/shared/_sort_dropdown.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_shared__sort_dropdown_html_erb___1598759478239571724_70137340818660'
app/views/films/index.html.erb:6:in `block in _app_views_films_index_html_erb___3440113417390236014_70137340622600'
app/views/films/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_films_index_html_erb___3440113417390236014_70137340622600'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:33:in `set_tenant_time_zone'
```

app/views/shared/_sort_dropdown.html.erb

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Sort: <strong><%= current[0].humanize %> <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-<%= current[1] == 'asc' ? 'up' : 'down' %>"></i></strong> 
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <% choices.each do |c| %>
      <li class="<%= "active" if params[:sort] == "#{c[0]}-#{c[1]}" %>">
      <%= link_to url_for(params.merge(sort: "#{c[0]}-#{c[1]}")) do %>
        <%= c[0].humanize %> <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-<%= c[1] == 'asc' ? 'up' : 'down' %>"></i>
      <% end %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is a button that sorts the data

Inside index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'shared/sort_dropdown', current: sort, choices: [['serial','desc'], ['area','asc'], ['shelf','asc']] %>
```

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_unsafe_h

Comment: looks as if you're trying to access the params hash directly in the view. You shouldn't do this, instead, 'sanitize' the params using the strong_parameters technique https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html. Also, stylistically, it's unusual to access params (or strong params) in the view. Normally it should be built on model instances. But you haven't shared enough of your app for us to understand what the controller is doing here.

Comment: The issue is covered in this question pretty well in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46029524/716